# Trying to download images from website with urllib.request but I'm getting a 403 error. How do I change the user agent?

Tags: python

I've written a program that goes to a specific website and finds the image URL, title and previous button URL. This is done using the requests and bs4 modules. I'm getting the URL's and everything okay but I can't seem to download the images. I keep getting a 403 error along with some other exceptions being raised. I know that the 403 error usually happens because the website is detecting that you're not using a browser so I went online to try and find out how to change the user agent. I've written some code to do that in the program but I'm not sure if I've done it correctly because a lot of tutorials/posts on stack exchange with this problem are using urllib2 or just plain urllib which has all been combined into urllib.request.

Here's the code:

```
   import bs4, requests, urllib.request, re, os

os.chdir(r'c:\Users\Adam\Desktop\pythonprogs\GuitarPics')   #change this to your current directory if needed

#this first chunk finds the comic number based on the html code from the page
url = 'http://www.guitargeek.com/michael-wilton-queensryche-guitar-rig-and-gear-setup-2007/'
res = requests.get(url)     #open initial  webpage
res.raise_for_status()      #raise exception if page doesnt work          

imageSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')  #parse html from page
search = True

#the comic number is then used to loop through the pages and extract the image and title and then save it to a folder.

while search == True:


    res = requests.get(url)          #open initial xkcd webpage
    res.raise_for_status()
    imageSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')  #parse html from page

    try:

        prevElem = imageSoup.select('#wrapper_main > div.rigview_nav_middle > div > div > span.pref > a')
        url = prevElem[0].get('href')

        imageElem = imageSoup.select('#entry > p > a > img')                      #get image element from html
        imageAttrs = imageElem[0].attrs
        imageURL = imageAttrs['src']

        titleElem = imageSoup.select('#content > div > h1')                 #finds comic title element
        title = titleElem[0].text.strip()                     #strips title element to just be title



    except:
        print('Not able to find image source')
        search = False #Sometimes this problem happens when there's no image on the page
        print(url)
        print(imageURL)
        continue

    if os.path.isfile(os.path.basename(imageURL)) == False:                 #if the image does not exist in folder, download it

        #try:
            class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
                version = "Mozilla/5.0"

            urllib._urlopener = AppURLopener()

            #Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11
            urllib.request.URLopener.version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0'
            resource = urllib.request.urlopen(imageURL)
            output = open(os.path.basename(imageURL),"wb")
            output.write(resource.read())
            output.close()
            print('Image ' + title + ' downloaded')

        #except:
            print('Failed to download this one, not an image?')     #Sometimes the file isn't an image and urllib fails to download it
            continue
    else:
        print('You already have this image (' + title + ')')                        


print('Finished.' + ' All images were downloaded to: ' + os.getcwd())
```

I'm specifically having problems with this:

```
 class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
            version = "Mozilla/5.0"

        urllib._urlopener = AppURLopener()

        #Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11
        urllib.request.URLopener.version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0'
        resource = urllib.request.urlopen(imageURL)
        output = open(os.path.basename(imageURL),"wb")
        output.write(resource.read())
        output.close()
```

So how do I go about changing the user agent successfully with urllib.request?

Answer (score 0):

For those that have the same problem down the road in the future, here is what I did to fix it.

```
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener

class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/2007127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
myopener=MyOpener()
myopener.retrieve(imageURL, title + '.jpg')
```